# How can I tag all upstream projects in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

We use Jenkins to build an ASP.NET solution for our clients.  We are using the standard Subversion feature as the repository plugin and MSBuild to make the builds.  Other plug-ins we are using are Copy Artifact, Publish over CIFS

In Jenkins, I have 5 jobs:

- Third-Party DLLs - A bunch of third-party DLLs/assemblies that are
  used throughout the project.  We only have binaries here
- Services - A group of projects that all us to consume third-party
  services.  Upstream of 'Third-Party DLLs'.
- Core - A core set of projects that contain all common assemblies used
  by all client implementations. Upstream of 'Third-Party DLLs',
  'Service'.
- ClientX - The client    specific implementation of this solution. 
  Upstream of 'Core'.
- ClientX (QA Deployment) - Moves code from a Dev server (where unit
  tests are ran) to a QA Server where QA can do their own testing.

Each downstream project pulls the artifacts from the upstream project.  Everything is working great and very stream-lined in moving code around.

What I'm looking for is this:
When the QA Deployment approves a build to be released, I want to tag the ClientX subversion code, the Core code, the Services code, and the Third-Party DLLs so that I can always get that build and everything used to make it, if needed.  Basically, I want to tag all upstream code/dependencies.

I've looked at several different plug-ins that give me upstream information so I can manually make the tag (Upstream Display Tag).  However, I'm looking for a one-click (or a few clicks) solution that will let me do this.

Is there anything already out there that I can leverage or any process I can utilized?  I've googled around and haven't found anything that seems to fit my need.

Comment: Your describing this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin